# Can Cloudfront access resources in a VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-vpc, amazon-elb

I want to connect Cloudfront to an internal load balancer which is connected to my application. Inbound traffic comes from a third party application so I cannot only use the internal load balancer.
The process would be:

```
third party app <-> cloudfront <-> internal load balacner <-> my application
```

However, I am not sure if Cloudfront can access the load balancer in my VPC.
Any ideas how that would that be setup?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately at this time there is no way to connect to private AWS resources, there are 2 types of Origin.

- S3 - A public S3 bucket, with security hardened between communication through the usage of [Origin Access Identity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html).
- Custom Domain - Forward to a publicly resolvable and connectable domain name. This is the option you would need to use.

Just because your load balancer is public you can still enhance your security to reduce the threat of an unknown source accessing your load balancer.

You could add a [custom header](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/add-origin-custom-headers.html) to your requests containing a secret. Then if you use an application load balancer attach a [WAF](https://aws.amazon.com/waf/) with a default to block all requests. Finally add an allow rule to WAF to allow where the header has a value of your secret.

Comment: What about configuring the `Restrict Viewer Access
(Use Signed URLs or
Signed Cookies)` to `Yes` in the Cloudfront distribution setttings? It states that viewers can use CloudFront signed URLs or signed cookies to access your (private) content.

Comment: This restricts private access to the CloudFront distribution not the origin itself.

Comment: So you're saying that my application has to be publicly accessible? Sorry I am new to AWS. I'm reading this article (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/serving-private-content-using-amazon-cloudfront-aws-lambdaedge/) that says I can use AWS Lambda to enforce access control to my private origin. It says I can "Whitelist Amazon CloudFront IPs on your custom origin’s firewall... If you have configured origin in a VPC, you can automatically update your Security Groups by using AWS Lambda." Would this be something to look into?

Comment: The load balancer would still need to be public for this. Yes you can look into this too to whitelist all of the CloudFront IP addresses but remember that anyone can create a CloudFront distribution and set your load balancer as an origin to bypass this. Thats why I would advise also adding a secret :)

Comment: Is there a way for me to use an internal load balancer?

Comment: There's no way at this time to use an internal load balancer with CloudFront. Sorry :(

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help Chris :) Do you happen to know of any other way I could go about this maybe without using Cloudfront? I just need a way to allow external inbound traffic to access my application on the internal load balancer in the VPC.

Comment: Where is the external source hosted?

Comment: It's a public Slack application, so whenever users press a button, it should send the request to my application.

Comment: Right in that case could you maybe look at using the following solution. CloudFront -> API Gateway -> VPCLink to internal network load balancer? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-private-integration.html. If its a simple API you can do it that way.

Comment: Thanks Chris! I'll look into that

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: Another approach is to have a public load balancer but restrict access to it using a security group containing the aws managed prefix list for CloudFront. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/working-with-aws-managed-prefix-lists.html